# Move map (google maps) when clicking address

Tags: java, primefaces, maps

im making a Poll's application, and i get the coordinates from the mobile device that was used to make the poll. I would like to show a list with all the coordinates of where a Poll was made. And them when the user click on the coordinates, the map (google maps) moves to that address. I can't find any similar code on google.  In resumen is something like this. You have a list with coordinates, and when you click in one, a map that would be at the side of the list will move to that address. Thanks a lot for any help.

Im working with java.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `geocoder.geocode( { 'address': sAddress},  function(results, status){` WHERE sAddress is a string containing the address (Street, City, State, etc.) and `map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);` inside the geocode function

Comment: I don't think he needs a geocoder since he has the coordinates already. Or am I missing something in the question?

Answer (score 0):

For the Java APIs for Android you must [change the view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views) of the camera. This includes both the 2D map features (position, zoom), but also the 3D ones (tilt, orientation). For the complete spec of the CameraPosition object that you need to create see the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#zoomIn%28%29).

So, having the coordinates, in the `OnClickListener` you must do something like:

```
GoogleMap myMap = mapFragment.getMap();
CameraUpdate campos = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(myLat, myLng));
myMap.moveCamera(campos);
```

where `mapFragment` is the MapFragment object you use in your `Activity`.

---

Below for javascript APIs:

For centering the map to certain coordinates, use the `panTo(latLng:LatLng)` function. More info you can fing in the [Google Maps V3 API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Add a `click` handler to the element in the list. In the handler, grab the reference to your google.maps.Map object and then call:

1. create the [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object:

   ```
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng);
   ```
2. recenter or pan the map to this location:

   ```
   myMap.panTo(latlng)
   ```

where `myMap` is the map object reference, and the `myLat` and `myLbg` are number values of your coordinates.

Comment: ummmm i already have the coordinates from the android phone.... here is an example of what i need.

Comment: What Maps API are you using. Are they listed here? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

Comment: nop... i get the coordinates from  an android phone... im making a webapp..... see the image http://chekspir.com/example.jpg

Comment: I saw the image. In that case, from the answer, user the 2nd part: javascript APIs.

Comment: Im using googlemaps.. but with primefaces....  so see this site: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapCircle.jsf and take a look to the MapBean.java file....

and to my screen: http://chekspir.com/example.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i will try it and let you know what happes... thanks

Comment: Sorry, in this case I cannot help you, I have no experience with primefaces and looking the their docs I only see "Map Events". Maybe you can bind somehow a listener like in this example with simple controls: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyAction.jsf

Answer (score 0):

OK.. i found my solution.. if someone is interested.. this works great for me..

$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();

```
$("#menu").on("click", "#panLA", function() {
    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.01131647557699, -118.25599389648437);
    map.panTo(laLatLng);
});
$("#menu").on("click", "#panLB", function() {
    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.70131647557699, -118.15599389648437);
    map.panTo(laLatLng);
});
```

});

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
}

http://jsfiddle.net/D2W3j/